# What front-end can I use with RPython to implement a language?

Tags: parsing, bison, lex, pypy

I've looked high and low for examples of implementing a language using the RPython toolchain, but the only one I've been able to find so far is [this](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/04/tutorial-writing-interpreter-with-pypy.html) one in which the author writes a simple BF interpreter. Because the grammar is so simple, he doesn't need to use a parser/lexer generator. Is there a front-end out there that supports developing a language in RPython?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any general lexer or parser generator targeting RPython specifically. Some with Python output *may* work, but I wouldn't bet on it. However, there's a set of parsing tools in [`rlib.parsing`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/pypy/en/latest/rlib.html#parsing). It seems quite usable. OTOH, there's a warning in the documentation: It's reportedly still in development, experimental, and only used for the Prolog interpreter so far.

Alternatively, you can write the frontend by hand. Lexers can be annoying and unnatural, granted (you may be able to rip out the utility modules for DFAs used by the Python implementation). But parsers are a piece of cake if you know the right algorithms. I'm a huge fan of "Top Down Operator Precedence parsers" a.k.a. "Pratt parsers", which are reasonably simple (recursive descent) but make all expression parsing issues (nesting, precedence, associativity, etc.) a breeze. There's depressingly little information on them, but the few blog posts were sufficient for me:

- One by [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html) (wouldn't recommend it though, it throws a whole lot of unrelated stuff into the parser and thus obscures it),
- another one at [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm) (uses Python),
- and a third by a sadly even-less-famous guy who's developing a language himself, [Robert Nystrom](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/).

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems strange for a such a successful project with an expressed interest in helping people to write their on languages not to have an easy lexing/parsing process. I'll jump into the rlib module -- since my aims are small in scope, it's possible I won't need anything more. Much obliged!

Comment: Something like http://fdik.org/pyPEG/ will work? I'm interesting in build a language too...

Comment: @mamcx Without inspecting the code, I can tell you that it's extremely unlikely that any Python library (parsing or otherwise) runs as RPython without severe modification.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Gaynor has [ported](https://github.com/alex/rply) David Beazley's excellent [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) to RPython. Its [documentation](https://rply.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is quite good, and he even gave a [talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/1694/so-you-want-to-write-an-interpreter) about using it to implement an interpreter at PyCon US 2013.

Comment: First attept to use: Rply incompatible with Ply at source level: need some lexergenerator comparing to Ply template import ply.lex as lex ..., and calls some RPython generation when started with python parser.py